How do I remove the four dots on the left og GNOME's top bar?
I am trying to get rid of the four dots at the top left, next to Places.

I went into the GNOME Extensions and tweaks menus but I do not see this referenced anywhere. As you can see from the screenshot I have another workspace manager on my taskbar so I don't really need the four dots and it honestly just gets in the way when I go to the top left.
Let me know and if you need other information or configs, etc., I'll be happy to provide.

you may also try this extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6272/add-custom-text-to-workspace-indicators/

The Gnome Shell extension Logo Activities by howbeau can replace the current indicator by either text (e.g. the former "Activities"), a static icon, both or nothing.
